# Distribution of $\operatorname{min}(X_i,H)$

Tags: probability, summation, conditional-probability

*A fair die is rolled six times. What are the expected value and the standard deviation of the smallest
number rolled?*

Let $X_i, \forall i=1,...,6$ be the outcomes of the roll and $H$ the highest outcome that I obtain. So I have to find the distribution of $Z=\operatorname{min}(X_i,H)$. I wrote:

$\mathbb{P}(Z)=\mathbb{P}[(Z\cap H=1)\cup ...\cup (Z\cap H=6)]=\mathbb{P}(Z\cap H=1)+...+\mathbb{P}(Z\cap H=6)=\sum_{j=1}^{6}\mathbb{P}(H=j)\mathbb{P}(Z|H=j)$

Now the problem: how do I have to calculate $\mathbb{P}(Z=z)=\sum_{j=1}^{6}\mathbb{P}(H=j)\mathbb{P}[\operatorname{min}(X_i,H=j)=z|H=j]$?

Thanks in advance for any help?

Comment: To compute the distribution on the minimum, $Z$, I think it is easier to compute $P(Z≥i)$.for each $i$.  You can then read off $P(Z=i)$.

Comment: @lulu Ok, you say $\mathbb{P}[\operatorname{min}[(X_i,j)=z|H=j]=\mathbb{P}(X\geq j|H=j)$. But the point is that I don't know neither $j$ nor $z$. Do I gradually have to assume their values? If it is, the first case should be simple: $\forall j=1,...,6\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\frac{1}{6}$. But for $\mathbb{P}(Z=2)$ we have $j=2,...,6$, so that's an exorbitant number of possibilities. Ie to say:

Comment: @lulu $\mathbb{P}(Z=2)=\mathbb{P}(H=2)\mathbb{P}[X\geq 2|H=2]+\sum_{j=3}^{6}\mathbb{P}(H=j)\mathbb{P}[\operatorname{min}(X_i,j)=2|H=j]$.

Comment: I don't understand.  Let $Z$ be the minimum of the $6$ tosses.  Then $P(Z≥1)=1$, clearly.  $P(Z≥2)=\left(\frac 56\right)^6$ (why?)  so $P(Z=1)=P(Z≥1)-P(Z≥2)=1-\left(\frac 56\right)^6$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu So $\mathbb{P}(Z=2)=1-(\frac{5}{6})^6-(\frac{4}{6})^6$?

Comment: Why would you think that?  Just go through the same steps I did in my comment.  I already did $P(Z≥2)$ for you so you just need to compute $P(Z≥3)$.

Comment: @lulu $\mathbb{P}(Z\geq 3)=1-\mathbb{P}(Z<3)=[1-\mathbb{P}(X_1=1\cup X_1=2)]\cdot ... \cdot [1-\mathbb{P}(X_6=1 \cup X_6=2)]=[1-\frac{2}{6}]\cdot ... \cdot [1-\frac{2}{6}]=(\frac{4}{6})^6$.

Comment: @lulu Now I have to apply $\mathbb{P}(X>k)=\mathbb{P}(X>k-1)-\mathbb{P}(X>k)$ like you said, but I don't understand if I have to leave the $1$ of $\mathbb{P}(Z\geq 1)$ in the following or not.

Comment: Your calculations tend to be much too complicated.  $P(Z≥3)=\left(\frac 46\right)^6$ because you need each toss separately to yield one of $3,4,5,6$.    And your equation for $P(X>k)$ does not make sense.  I think you are trying to write $P(X=k)=P(X≥k)-P(X≥k+1)$, where $X$ is the minimum.  But I am not sure.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that was a typo. So $\mathbb{P}(Z=3)=(\frac{5}{6})^6-(\frac{4}{6})^6$ or $1-(\frac{5}{6})^6-(\frac{4}{6})^6$? Do I have to leave the $1$ in the following?

Comment: I think you are trying to guess at the answer, and I don't understand why.  What you actually write is so filled with errors that it is hard to sort out.   I already told you that $P(Z=2)=P(Z≥2)-P(Z≥3)$ and we have explicit formulas for both the terms on the right.

Comment: @lulu Please excuse me, I'm so tired. Anyway the expected value is $1,44$.

Comment: Yes, that looks good.  I got $1.4397$ to $4$ places.